# How to Insert a Visible Autofiltered Row into Another Sheet (Excluding Header)

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to AutoFilter (in column A of SHEET 1) the Active Cell in **SHEET 2**. Then I have an IF Statement that counts the number of Visible Rows, and if it is more than 1 (to exclude the header) then I would like to insert a new row into **SHEET 3** and cut and paste the values of the Auto filtered Row in **SHEET 1** into the new row in **SHEET 3**.

Then I clear the Auto Filter in **SHEET 1**, and insert a new row into **SHEET 1** and cut and paste the values of the Active Cell's Row from **SHEET 2** into the new row in **SHEET 1**. 
IF there are no results from the Auto Filter in SHEET 1, then the ELSE STATEMENT clears the Auto Filter in **SHEET 1**, inserts a new row into SHEET 1 and cut and pastes the values of the Active Cell's Row from **SHEET 2** into the new row in **SHEET 1**.

Currently, I can't seem to get my code to work if the Auto Filter results in **SHEET 2** are in any rows > Row 2. Here is my current code, I have commented to help with navigation:

```
Sub Autofilter_Macro()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = Sheet1
Set sh2 = Sheet2
Set sh3 = Sheet3

Dim rng As Range

Dim AC As Integer
AC = ActiveCell.Row

sh1.AutoFilterMode = False 'Clears any AutoFilters from Sheet1

sh1.Range("A:A").Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value 'AutoFilters SHEET 1 column "A" based off the ActiveCell Row in SHEET 2

Set rng = sh1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'Sets rng to visible cells

'    If (rng.Rows.Count > 1) Then 'Counts the # of visible rows
    If rng.Areas.Count = 2 Then

        sh3.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow 'Inserts an empty row (with the same format as the one below it) into row 2 of SHEET 3

'        sh3.Range("A2:CK2").Value = rng.Offset(rowOffSet:=1).Value 'Sets the new empty row's values in SHEET 3 = the values of the Autofiltered row in SHEET
        rng.Rows(2).Value.Cut sh3.Range("A2")

        sh1.ShowallData 'Clears any Autofilters from SHEET 1

        sh1.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow 'Inserts an empty row (with the same format as the one below it) into row 2 of SHEET 1

        sh1.Range("A2:CK2").Value = sh2.Range(Cells(AC, 1), Cells(AC, 89)).Value 'Sets the new empty row's values in SHEET 1 = the values of the ActiveCell row in SHEET 2

        MsgBox "Replaced Main Database" 'MsgBox indicating what has executed

    Else

        sh1.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow 'Inserts an empty row (with the same format as the one below it) into row 2 of SHEET 1

        sh1.Range("A2:CK2").Value = sh2.Range(Cells(AC, 1), Cells(AC, 89)).Value 'Sets the new empty row's values in SHEET 1 = the values of the ActiveCell row in SHEET 2

        MsgBox "New Entry into Main Database"

    End If

sh1.ShowallData 'Clears any Auotfilters from SHEET 1


End Sub
```

Thank you to CDP1802 for his answer below, here is the final code for anyone using this as reference:

```
Sub Autofilter_Macro()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet                       'Declares variables as worksheets
    Dim rng As Range                                                               'Declares variable as a range to store values

    Set sh1 = Sheet1                                                               'Assigns a worksheet to the declared worksheet variable (sh1 = "Main Database" Worksheet = Machine Inv #)
    Set sh2 = Sheet2                                                               'Assigns a worksheet to the declared worksheet variable (sh 2 = "Changes" Worksheet)
    Set sh3 = Sheet3                                                               'Assigns a worksheet to the declared worksheet variable (sh 3 = "Historical Parameters" Worksheet)

    Dim rowAC As Long, rowCut As Long                                              'Declares variable and assigns it as a Long data type
    rowAC = ActiveCell.Row                                                         'Sets the Long variable as the Active Cell Row

    If Len(ActiveCell.Value) = 0 Then                                              'Tests if the Active Cell in column A (Key) of the "Changes" Worksheet is blank or not

        MsgBox "Blank Key in:" & ActiveCell.Address, vbCritical                    'If the Active Cell is blank, then this MsgBox notifies you that it's blank
        Exit Sub                                                                   'Ends the entire Macro if the Active Cell is Blank

    End If                                                                         'Doesn't initiate the MsgBox and continues the Macro if the Key in Column A is not blank

    sh1.AutoFilterMode = False                                                     'Clears any Autofilters (if any) in Sheet 1
    sh1.Range("A:A").Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value              'Autofilters Sheet 1 for the Active Cell (Key) from Sheet 2 ("Changes" Worksheet)

    Set rng = sh1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)                        'Sets the range varaible to visible cells in Sheet 1 (Main Database)

    If rng.Areas(1).Rows.Count > 1 Then                                            'Tests if the Active Cell (Key) from Sheet 2 (Changes) is in Row 2 of Sheet 1

        rowCut = rng.Areas(1).Rows(2).Row                                          'If the key is present, stores the values of Row 2 in Sheet 1 as a variable called "rowCut"

    ElseIf rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then                                                'Tests if the Active Cell (Key) from Sheet 2 (Changes) is present in any Row of Sheet 1 (Excluding Row 1 "The Header", and Row 2)

        rowCut = rng.Areas(2).Rows(1).Row                                          'If the key is present, stores the values of the row that has the Active Cell "Key" in Sheet 1 as a variable called "rowCut"

    End If                                                                         'If the Key is not present in Sheet 1, the variable "rowCut" will not hold any values and be equal to zero

    sh1.ShowallData                                                                'Clears Autofilters in Sheet 1

    If rowCut > 0 Then                                                             'If the variable "rowCut" was succesful in holding a row's values from Sheet 1, then the following executes:

        sh3.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow 'Inserts an empty row into Sheet 3 Row 2 w/ same format as the row below it
        sh1.Rows(rowCut).Copy sh3.Range("A2")                                      'Copies the Active (Cell) Row from Sheet 1 (Main Database) & pastes it into the empty row 2 in Sheet 3 (Historical Parameters)
        sh1.Rows(rowCut).Delete                                                    'Deletes the Active (Cell) Row from Sheet 1

    End If                                                                         'If the variable "rowCut" was unsuccesful in holding a row's values from Sheet 1, then nothing will happen to Sheet 3 (Historical Parameters)

        sh1.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow 'Inserts an empty row into Sheet 1 Row 2 w/ same format as the row below it
        sh2.Range("A" & rowAC & ":CK" & rowAC).Copy sh1.Range("A2")                'Copies the Active (Cell) Row from Sheet 2 (Changes) & pastes it into the empty row 2 in Sheet 1
        sh2.Range("A" & rowAC & ":CK" & rowAC).Delete                              'Deletes the Active (Cell) Row from Sheet 2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the visible range is non-contiguous like "$A$1:$D$1,$A$6:$D$6" so the rng.Offset(rowOffSet:=1) will always give $A$2:$D$2. Range has a [areas property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas). Using rng.areas.count you can do something like

```
If rng.Areas.Count = 1 Then
   sh3.Range("A2:CK2").Value = rng.Offset(rowOffSet:=1).value
Else
   sh3.Range("A2:CK2").Value = rng.Areas(2).value     
End If
```

This is the test program I used

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
      Set rng = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    If rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
       Debug.Print "Rng", rng.Address
       Debug.Print "Rng Offset", rng.Offset(rowOffSet:=1).Address
       Debug.Print "rng Area(2)", rng.Areas(2).Address
    Else
       Debug.Print "rng", rng.Address
       Debug.Print "rng offset", rng.Offset(rowOffSet:=1).Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit - Incorporating that principle into your code I get

```
Sub Autofilter_Macro()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheet1
    Set sh2 = Sheet2
    Set sh3 = Sheet3

    Dim rowAC As Long, rowCut As Long
    rowAC = ActiveCell.Row

    If Len(ActiveCell.Value) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Blank value in " & ActiveCell.Address, vbCritical
       Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "Value = " & ActiveCell.Value

    'AutoFilters SHEET 1 column "A" based off the ActiveCell Row in SHEET 2
    sh1.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh1.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value

    'Sets rng to visible cells
    Set rng = sh1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If rng.Areas(1).Rows.Count > 1 Then
         rowCut = rng.Areas(1).Rows(2).Row
    ElseIf rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
         rowCut = rng.Areas(2).Rows(1).Row
    End If
    sh1.ShowAllData 'Clears any Auotfilt

    If rowCut > 0 Then
        'Inserts an empty row into Sheet 3 Row 2
        'with the same format as the one below it
        'copy/paste/delete filter row to sheet3
        sh3.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
            CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

        sh1.Rows(rowCut).EntireRow.Copy
        sh3.Activate
        sh3.Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        sh1.Activate
        'sh1.Range("A" & rowCut).Interior.Color = vbRed
        sh1.Rows(rowCut).Delete
    End If

    'insert row in sheet1 and copy from sheet2
    sh1.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

    sh2.Range("A" & rowAC & ":CK" & rowAC).Copy
    sh1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to set it as an area, and attempted the following: ```If rng.Areas.Count = 0 Then
                      sh1.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
sh1.Range("A2:CK2").Value = sh2.Range(Cells(AC, 1), Cells(AC, 89)).Value
Else
sh3.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
sh3.Rows("2:2") = rng.Areas(2).Value
rng.Areas(1).Value = sh2.Range(Cells(AC, 1), Cells(AC, 89)).Value``` But I keep receiving an error when my Auto filter is in Row 2 in Sheet 1, but it works of the Auto filtered row is coming from Rows > 2 in Sheet 1

Comment: @Handreen I've not tested it but think you need to account for an area count of 0,1 and 2 or more as 3 separate cases, So IF count = 0 … ELSEIF count =1... ELSE … END IF

Comment: I am trying to replace ```sh3.Range("A2:CK2").Value = rng.Offset(rowOffSet:=1).Value``` with ```rng.Rows(2).Value.Cut sh3.Range("A2")``` as I want to cut and paste the Autofiltered row from Sheet 1 (sh1) into a newly inserted blank row in Sheet 3 (sh3), but it seems to keep giving me a Run-Time error '424': https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-required-error-424?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1000424)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: I have updated my post and commented out the old lines above the newly suggested ones, please let me know what you find

Comment: Yes, Col A on Sheet 1 has a header in row 1

Comment: Yes, basically the active row from Sheet 2 should be inserted into row 2 of sheet 1 (that's what my current code is attempting), but I actually want it to replace the Auto filtered row in Sheet 1 (if any) with the Active Row values from Sheet 2 and insert the Sheet 1 Auto filtered row into Row 2 of Sheet 3, and IF there are no auto filter results, then simply insert a new Row 2 into Sheet 1 and cut/paste the active row from Sheet 2 into Sheet 1 and do nothing to Sheet 3. (I have updated my post) Please let me know if this makes sense, and thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: @Handreen OK I updated my answer. I used copy/delete instead of cut to get values only. If the active.cell content is blank you get strange results so I added test for that. It's not tested fully but hopefully gets you progress.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have updated my post to reflect my final code. Thanks again for taking the time to understand my requirements and delivering such a great solution, all the best - Handreen